# plotly fig stopped to output chart in Jupyter

Tags: plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

```py
import plotly.express as px

print(f"{df.to_pandas()['decrease_percentage']}")
```

outputs

```
0        -0.01
1         0.00
2        -0.01
3         0.00
4         0.00
          ... 
299295    0.00
299296    0.00
299297    0.00
299298    0.00
299299   -5.67
Name: decrease_percentage, Length: 299300, dtype: float64
```

So the data is there

```py
fig = px.histogram(df.to_pandas(), x="decrease_percentage", log_y=True, nbins=20, text_auto=True,
                   width=1600, title="decrease_percentage")
fig.update_traces(xbins_size=1)
fig.show()
```

stopped to output histogram image at Jupiter.
Tried to restart, reload, e.t.c., nothing helps.

Tried postgressql query, works well
[image]
so there is chart-able data. And I was able to chart before. Don't understand what did I break.

Debugger shows that there is some data at figure..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's some JetBrains DataSpell issue. It stops to render charts with millions of points

```py
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
```

helps since charts are rendered in your default browser. Not convenient since charts and notebook are not together, but works as workaround.